# backtracking failing for some N queen problem scenarios

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking, n-queens

I need to write an algorithm who solve the problem using backtracking. 
I came up with the following code:

```
public boolean queenPuzzleRec(int queens) {

    if(queens == SIZE) {
        boardToString();
        return true;

    }
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<SIZE; j++) {
            if(Legal(i, j)) { 
                board[i][j]=true; 
                if(queenPuzzleRec(queens+1)) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    board[i][j]=false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The code works only for some of the board sizes, but not for all of them.
For example, for SIZE = 6 the solution will be as followed:

1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   **1**
0   0   0   0   **1**   0
0   0   **1**   0   0   0
0   **1**   0   0   0   0

It will do the same mistake (The two diagonal next to each other) also for SIZE = 8,10 and 11 for example, but won't do it for 4,5,7, or 9.

SIZE = 4 solutions

0   **1**   0   0
0   0   0   **1**
**1**   0   0   0
0   0   **1**   0

Meanwhile, i read about the right algorithm, but I don't get why mine doesn't work well.
BTW the problem is not at the Legal(i,j) method ( I checked the problematic scenarios, and also used it with the working code - but of course I'll add it if it's necessary)

Just to make clear again - I don't need an answer to the problem, I would like to know what the problem with my code.

Thank you

Edit - Legal func:

```
public boolean Legal(int i, int j) {

    if (i >= SIZE || j >= SIZE) {
        return false;
    }

    // checks row
    for (int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++) {
        if (board[i][k] == true) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // checks col
    for (int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++) {
        if (board[k][j] == true)
            return false;
    }

    int row = i;
    int col = j;
    // first diagonal forward
    while (row < SIZE && col < SIZE) {
        if (board[row][col] == true)
            return false;
        row++;
        col++;
    }


    row = i;
    col = j;

    // first diagonal backward
    while (row >= 0 && col >= 0) {
        if (board[row][col] == true)
            return false;
        row--;
        col--;
    }

    row = i;
    col = j;

    // second diagonal forward
    while (row >= 0 && col < SIZE) {
        if (board[row][col] == true)
            return false;
        row--;
        col++;
    }

    row = i; 
    col = j; 

    // second diagonal backward
    while (row < SIZE && col >= 0) {
        if (board[i][j] == true)
            return false;
        row++;
        col--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: My bet is that there is a bug in `Legal`

Comment: Have you considered using a debugger or writing unit tests?

Comment: @Sylwester I added it, but once again - I use the same Legal for a function who does the work properly

Comment: @akuzminykh I don't know how to, but I'll try to learn - have any tips?

Comment: @RedYoel There are probably more than enough guides on the web that teach you how to debug code and/or write unit tests. Just start doing research. Good luck!

Comment: Just make sure your diagonal logic in legal function is correct; print all diagonals calculated; Also according to your logic you always place queen at first position; this will not always work

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava my legal function work, as i said i use the same one for a slightly different code and it works. I've also **"checked the problematic scenarios"**

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is

```
 for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<SIZE; j++) {
            if(Legal(i, j)) { 
                board[i][j]=true; 
                if(queenPuzzleRec(queens+1)) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    board[i][j]=false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The position 0,0 will always be legal according to this logic, This leads to always facing the problem of having queen at 0,0; but if you look at solution for size 6.

[image]

There is no queen at any corner, you need to consider all situations i.e. using both cases if you place it on a legal position or skip it. This will create a branching if possible at every legal detected by your legal function.

Comment: I understand what are you saying, but the solution for size 4 is as i edited at the post.
as you can see it doesn't start at (0,0)

Comment: hmm interesting i do not see how it works for 4 can you share the snippet for the main function on how u call this, also i am at work will see it later

Comment: simply:
QueenSolver queen = new QueenSolver(); // the constructor "builds" the board
queen.queenPuzzleRec(0); // 0 queens placed

Comment: @RedYoel now i have time just send me the script then i can help u debug, use something like online code share

Comment: Not correct since when all possibilities with first queen in 0,0 then it wil continue to 0,1. The last queen cannot be placed means `board[i][j] = false` al the way back and then the first queen in moved... Because of this an optimization would be to pass i+1,0 as the first possible next position.